# Move and grow partition

Tags: partitioning, system-reserved-partition

I have a disk containing

- a bunch of free space in the front (111GB)
- then a "System Reserved" partition (350 MB)
- and then a partition that Windows maps to my C drive, which is my system drive.

I would like to enlarge that last partition. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/), or any Linux CD that has GParted in it. It can both move and reliably resize NTFS partitions. (Best to avoid *swapping* them, though.)

Use GParted to move the "reserved" partition to the beginning of the disk (the program will probably insist on leaving the first 1–2 MB free); then move the C:\ partition next to it; and finally use either GParted or Windows' own diskmgmt.msc to grow C:\ to fill the available space.